# SOLID in Python

Tags: python, exception, solid-principles

Sorry if my question bad or wrong, but i want to know.

```
class MyCustomException(KeyError):
  def __init__(self, *args):
    super().__init__(*args)


def method(d):
  return d['name']

try:
  d = {"value": 1}
  method(d)
except MyCustomException:
  print('got it')
```

Aaaand it does not work! I cant catch exception. Does this behaviour breaks SOLID priciple, Liskov substitution principle?

Comment: However, `try: raise MyCustomException() except KeyError: print('got it')` will work. Can you see why?

Comment: `MyCustomException ` inherits from `KeyError`, not the other way around

Comment: All exceptions ultimately inherit from `Exception`,  so you can see why it would be problematic if the behaviour worked as you suggest

Comment: @Chris_Rands it is not a problem in Java.

Comment: i never mentioned Java

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to explicitly throw your custom exception.

```
class MyCustomException(KeyError):
  pass

def method(d):
  if not 'name' in d:
    raise MyCustomException('name not found!')
  else:
    return d['name']

try:
  d = {"value": 1}
  method(d)
except MyCustomException:
  print('got it')
```

Liskov Substitution essentially means: If I have a class, and I subclass it, then that subclass should be able to work exactly the same way as the super class, if used as a super class.

In other words, I create a class `Baker` that can accept white bread and wheat bread. If I subclass `Baker` into a class `ArtisanBaker` that only accepts white bread, I've now broken Liskov Substitution. I can no longer use `ArtisanBaker` simply as a `Baker`.

Comment: it's a good way, but i want to know about SOLID Liskov principle behaviour

Comment: See my edit. I've tried to clarify what Liskov Substitution means. Your class doesn't affect it at all.

Answer (score 1):

Quote from the docs, [section 8.3](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html):

> A class in an except clause is compatible with an exception if it is the same class or a base class thereof (but not the other way around — **an except clause listing a derived class is not compatible with a base class**).

Yet this code doesn't break the substitution principle as the child class certainly provides the same methods as the base class, if they aren't overridden in a way that deviates from the base class' behavior, but your code doesn't do that.

BTW, you don't have to implement any methods to "rename" a class in such a way. You can simply do this:

```
class MyCustomException(KeyError):
    ...
```